# How to change custom post type slug without damage seo?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I need to change the structure of the taxonomy which holds a list of products, actually I have this implementation:

```
http://example.com/watches-product/category/product-name/
```

but this should be:

```
http://example.com/watches/product/category/product-name/
```

So actually I have to separate `watches-product` into `watches/product`, is possible do this without lose the SEO indexability?

This is the current code:

```
register_taxonomy('wpsc_watch_product_category', 'wpsc_watch_product', array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'query_var' => 'watch_product_category',
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'watches-product'
    ),
    'labels' => $labels,
));

register_post_type('wpsc_watch_product', array(
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => __('watches-product', "example") . '/%category%',
        'with_front' => true
    ),
    'taxonomies' => array('wpsc_watch_product_category'),
));
```

After this change (even if is possible) I would like that when an user visit the page:

```
http://example.com/watches-product/category/product-name/
```

the site will redirect him automatically to:

```
http://example.com/watches/product/category/product-name/
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this article can help, it doesn't matter if its custom post types or normal blog posts, SEO indexes your pages and uses its slug to be identified by people on the web, changing slug will always have a negative effect on your SEO but if you do it right it will recover pretty quickly. https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-change-a-blogs-permalinks-and-not-lose-all-organic-traffic/

Comment: Why not using redirection (301) plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without losing SEO.

1. Change the taxonomy slug from "watches-product" to "watches/product"

`register_taxonomy('wpsc_watch_product_category', 'wpsc_watch_product', array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'query_var' => 'watch_product_category',
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'watches/product'
    ),
    'labels' => $labels,
));`

2. Install a 302 Redirect Plugin. This plugin will redirect all the traffic to new url.